# Element doesn't show at all with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create span which after clicking shows the element (div) - in JavaScript obviosly.
I tried this:

js

```
let content = document.getElementsByClassName('content');

document.getElementById("show").addEventListener("click", function() {
  content.style.display = "block";
});
```

html

```
<div class="logo">
            <span id="show">atelophobia</span>
        </div>


<div class="content" style="display: none;">
        <span id="text"><span>test</span></span><br>
    </div>
```

but it doesn't work, and I don't know what to do now. I tried several different options but it all give the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a list of elements, you will then need to get the required item from the array and change its style.

Also I would recommend declaring your variable inside the click listener function. So something like this:

```
document.getElementById("show").addEventListener("click", function() {
   let content = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
   content.style.display = "block";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The getElementsByClassName will create an array of values.

`let content = document.getElementsByClassName('content');`

`content.style.display = "block";`

Won't actually work because you don't have an index of the content.

```js
let content = document.getElementsByClassName('content');

document.getElementById("show").addEventListener("click", function() {
  content[0].style.display = "block";
});
```

```html
<div class="logo">
 <span id="show">atelophobia</span>
</div>
<div class="content" style="display: none;">
 <span id="text"><span>test</span></span><br>
</div>
```

If you want to use one value,  you can use querySelector or getElementById

```js
let content = document.querySelector('.content');

document.getElementById("show").addEventListener("click", function() {
  content.style.display = "block";
});
```

```html
<div class="logo">
 <span id="show">atelophobia</span>
</div>
<div class="content" style="display: none;">
 <span id="text"><span>test</span></span><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to note that getElementsByClassName returns an 'array-like object', a collection,, not an array so you can use [0] to get its first entry, for example, but you can't do all the array operations on it. See [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your `getElementsByClassName` to use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead.

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object, for your purpose you only need to return a single element.

See the working snippet below:

```js
let content = document.querySelector('.content');

document.getElementById("show").addEventListener("click", function() {
  content.style.display = "block";
});
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <span id="show">atelophobia</span>
</div>


<div class="content" style="display: none;">
  <span id="text"><span>test</span></span><br>
</div>
```